# Pool Multiprocessing Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool, worker

Basically the issue is as follows: I have a bunch of workers that have a function prescribed to each (the function is worker(alist) ) and am trying to process 35 workers at the same time. Each worker reads their line from the file (the modulo part) and should process the line using the "worker" function. I've pen-tested and found that the raw manipulation and deletion of the useless indices is working 100% as intended.

The args part of the "pool.apply_async" function isn't passing the list "raw" into it and starting the process. Raw is completely correct and functions normally, worker by itself functions normally, the pool.apply_async function is the only place that there seems to be an issue and I have no idea how to fix it. Any help please?

The relevant code is here:

```
NUM_WORKERS=35
f=open("test.csv")
pool=multiprocessing.Pool()
open("final.csv",'w')
for workernumber in range(1, NUM_WORKERS):
    for i,line in enumerate(f):
        if i==0:
            print "Skipping first line" #dont do anything
        elif i%workernumber==0:
            raw = line.split(',')[0][1:-1].split()
            uselessindices=[-2,-3,-4,-5,-6]
            counter=0
            for ui in uselessindices:
                del raw[ui+counter]
                counter+=1
            print raw
            pool.apply_async(worker, args=(raw,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Why are you looping over the `workernumber` at all? Do you really want the first worker to process every line in the file and the second worker to process every other line? I don't see any reason to expect processing a line more than once would have any benefit, but maybe I'm missing something. Or do you actually want each line to be processed once? If so, the outer loop is entirely pointless (as is the condition on the `elif`).

Comment: 35 is a lot of processors.

Comment: @101 I was using an arbitrary number for the num_workers. There are 16 processors but the operation isn't CPU intensive, it just needs to be done by a shit ton of workers and compiled. I'm a beginner at multiprocessing and am trying to wade my way through the documentation. Is there a way to do this better?

Comment: @Blckknght You're totally right about the workernumber thing and I need to fix it. It should show i%NUM_WORKERS==workernumber so worker1 gets lines 1, 36, 71, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(arg):
    print 'doing work "%s"' % arg
    return

NUM_WORKERS=35
with open('test.csv', 'w') as test:
    for i in xrange(100):
        if i % 10 == 0:
            test.write('\n')
        test.write('"%s 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23",' % i)

f=open("test.csv")
pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=NUM_WORKERS)
open("final.csv",'w')

for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    raw = line.split(',')[0][1:-1].split()
    uselessindices=[-2,-3,-4,-5,-6]
    counter=0
    for ui in uselessindices:
        del raw[ui+counter]
        counter+=1
    pool.apply_async(worker, args=(raw,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
print 'last raw len: %s' % len(raw)
print 'last raw value: %s' % raw
```

Output:

```
doing work "['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '23']"
doing work "['10', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '23']"
doing work "['20', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '23']"
doing work "['30', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '23']"
doing work "['40', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '23']"
doing work "['50', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '23']"
doing work "['60', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '23']"
doing work "['70', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '23']"
doing work "['80', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '23']"
doing work "['90', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '23']"
last raw len: 19
last raw value: ['90', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '23']
```

Comment: The list might not be getting passed in properly because the line         raw = lines[i].split(',')[0][1:-1].split()
If you can provide a sample line, maybe I can check that for you.

Comment: I've checked the raw and the list data of raw and it is being passed in correctly. I tried to run your code to no avail; the worker is still not running at all. A simple print at the beginning of worker isn't being executed but the script runs with no errors which is what was happening before too.

Comment: I added some test data, to demonstrate how your code will process a csv with 10 values per line, each value holding a string of 24 separate parts, thus giving a raw length of 19 once the useless parts are removed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put the calculation of `raw` into a generator function, and then use [`Pool.imap_unordered()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered) or `Pool.map()` to run `worker()` over all of the items in the generator.

Something like this untested code:

```
def get_raw():
    with open("test.csv", 'rU') as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if i == 0:
                # skip header
                continue
            raw = line.split(',')[0][1:-1].split()
            uselessindices=[-2,-3,-4,-5,-6]  
            counter=0
            for ui in uselessindices:
                del raw[ui+counter]
                counter+=1
            yield raw

pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=NUM_WORKERS)

pool.map(worker, get_raw())
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: raw has 19 values and a 19 value list is what's needed for the worker to continue on its path. The error I get here when I've changed the code is now the following:


    pool.map(worker, get_raw())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
ValueError: need more than 19 values to unpack

Comment: Error occurring now after I fixed all the other issues that were occurring before: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects.

If i change it to imap_unordered instead of map, it works fine but map continues to not work properly. imap_unordered and async don't work because they're writing to a file and it only outputs 117 lines instead of the expected 1000 when using both of those. I read somewhere else that you shouldn't for file writing use async and instead should use map, hence why i'm trying this solution. Any advice?

Comment: This is the code for worker; assume everything is working perfectly here:

`def worker(alist):`
 `variable1,variable2...variable20 = tuple(alist)`
 `with open("final.csv", 'a') as myfile:`
  `finalVector = makeSingleVector(variable1,variable2,variable3...variable20)`
  `for item in finalVector:`
   `myfile.write("%s," % item)`
  `myfile.write("\n")`
 `return`

Answer (score 0):

So I found out it wasn't throwing an error that was occurring inside the worker as a result of a mismatched number of inputs into a child function (AKA worker was calling another function dosomething(a1,a2,...a20) and was only giving it 19 inputs). It seems async won't throw error outputs about issues happening inside the worker which is quite annoying but I now understand. Thanks for all the help!